# Wrapping array values based on time frames

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I have an array of months. My goal is to display these months on the x-axis of a chart. I have been trying to work out a way to ensure that the correct number of months, in the correct order are displayed for the filter options. The first four options are working but I've gotten stuck with the last filter option (1 Year).

This is my code as it stands. As I said above the first four filter options are working but the "1Year" option is only showing Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr (same as year-to-date)

```
public dealValueCategories: string[] = [
    'JAN',
    'FEB',
    'MAR',
    'APR',
    'MAY',
    'JUN',
    'JUL',
    'AUG',
    'SEP',
    'OCT',
    'NOV',
    'DEC',
  ];

public displayedMonths: string[] = [];

  public updateXAxisLabels(filter: string): void {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
    const monthNames = [
      'JAN',
      'FEB',
      'MAR',
      'APR',
      'MAY',
      'JUN',
      'JUL',
      'AUG',
      'SEP',
      'OCT',
      'NOV',
      'DEC',
    ];

    let startMonthIndex: number;
    let numOfMonths: number;

    switch (filter) {
      case 'YearToDate':
        startMonthIndex = 0;
        numOfMonths = currentMonth + 1;
        break;
      case '1Month':
        startMonthIndex = currentMonth;
        numOfMonths = 1;
        break;
      case '3Month':
        startMonthIndex = (currentMonth - 2 + 12) % 12;
        numOfMonths = 3;
        break;
      case '6Month':
        startMonthIndex = (currentMonth - 5 + 12) % 12;
        numOfMonths = 6;
        break;
      case '1Year':
        startMonthIndex = (currentMonth + 11) % 12;
        numOfMonths = 13;
        break;
      default:
        startMonthIndex = 0;
        numOfMonths = currentMonth + 1;
        break;
    }

    const displayedMonthsTemp = [...monthNames, ...monthNames];
    this.displayedMonths = displayedMonthsTemp.slice(
      startMonthIndex,
      startMonthIndex + numOfMonths
    );
  }
```

Comment: working as expected for me: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wg9Lk1cf/). Is it possible you're passing the filter name incorrectly? It looks like it might be falling through since the `default` is the same as `YearToDate`

Comment: My apology I forgot to get back to you! That was the issue. Thanks for your help! :)